# Changing heading into textbox dynamically

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="form_title">
    <h1>Form Title</h1>
</div>
```

This is my HTML code. I want to make a text box appear whereby user can change the value of h1 and save it.

Here is my attempt.

```
$('#form_title').click(function() {
    $(this).html('<input id="form_title_value" name="form_title_value"
                         type="text" placeholder="Enter Form Title..."> ');
});​
```

The problem is that the textbox looses focus when I click on it.

Comment: **What does** _"textbox does not seem to retain its value"_ **means?** What do you want to do with the textbox? and I can't see why the `<h1>` text should change with your's code.

Comment: It loose focus when I click on it.

Comment: @sarwar026. The problem is that he override the input on each click.

Comment: It's losing focus because the function fires every time you click on it (clicking the input is still technically clicking `#form_title`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('#form_title').one('click', function() {
    $(this).html('<input id="form_title_value" name="form_title_value" 
                         type="text" placeholder="Enter Form Title...">')
               .find('input').focus();
})​;
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRBuE/)

The problem is that you override the innerHTML of the div with each click.
So it no just "loose focus"  but it loose the innerHTML with each click.

`one` lets you attach a callback that will fire only once.

---

You can try [**this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ETvPS/3/) as well, that shows you how you can change the `<h1>` text

Comment: Nice touch with `focus()`. I'm guessing this is a thing that will be toggled, so not 100% `one()` will suit OP's needs. I can't say for sure though because the code looks half-baked.

Comment: @Madmartigan. There are other options, like with delegate events, but I need more context to know how to "attack the problem" `one` is **one** way... **:)**